# Is it possible to create a WPF tab control template that looks nothing like a tab control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol, controltemplate

What I'd like is a control that functions just like the tab control but instead of having the tabs along the top, the items would be displayed in a list box along the side. I imagine it's possible but haven't found any examples, I'm hoping there's someone here that's done something like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use a `TabControl` at all. You could just bind your `ListBox` to a list of items, and put a `ContentControl` beside it, bound to the selected item :

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox Name="listBox"
             DockPanel.Dock="Left"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource theTemplate}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: He-he :). You wrote this faster than I hit "Post Your Answer" button. Just wanted to write about master-details scenario with ListBox, but you made it faster :). Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

WPF controls are designed to enable exactly what you want. To reuse control functionality while completely replacing the visual representation. You will have to create your own `ControlTemplate` for the `TabControl`. You can find a [TabControl ControlTemplate Example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx). You will also have to study the [Control Authoring Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx).

I actually find the Silverlight 3 documentation somewhat easier to digest, and even though there are some differences when it comes to control styling the fundamental concepts are still the same. You can read [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(VS.95).aspx) to learn about control templates and then study [TabControl Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035(VS.95).aspx) to discover what is required to create you own control template in Silverlight.

You can use Expression Blend to extract the the default `TabControl` template in WPF.

Comment: Great writeup that sums up the power and intent of WPF controls nicely. I have yet to be deemed worthy of the ability to up vote, otherwise this is another useful answer I would have given credit to. Maybe I'll remember to come back to this one since it's on my own question if I ever do reach that point.